# Filter list of points using list of Polygons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography

Given a list of points and a list of polygons. How do you return a list of points (subset of original list of points) that is in any of the polygons on the list

I've removed other columns in the sample tables to simplify things

**Points Table:**

```
| Longitude| Latitude  |
|----------|-----------|
| 7.07491  | 51.28725  |
| 3.674765 | 51.40205  |
| 6.049105 | 51.86624  |
```

**LocationPolygons Table:**

```
|     LineString       |
|----------------------|
| CURVEPOLYGON (COMPOUNDCURVE (CIRCULARSTRING (-122.20 47.45, -122.81 47.0, -122.942505 46.687131 ...  |
| MULTIPOLYGON (((-110.3086 24.2154, -110.30842 24.2185966, -110.3127...
```

If I had row from the LocationPolygons table I could do something like

```
DECLARE @homeLocation geography;  
SET @homeLocation = (select top 1 GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(LineString, 4326)
FROM LocationPolygon where LocationPolygonId = '123abc')

select Id, Longitude, Latitude, @homeLocation.STContains(geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)) 
as IsInLocation from Points PointId in (1, 2, 3,)
```

which would return what I want in a format like the below. However this is only true for just one location on the list

```
| Id | Longitude| Latitude  | IsInLocation |
|----|----------|-----------|--------------|
| 1  | 7.07491  | 51.28725  | 0            |
| 2  | 3.674765 | 51.40205  | 1            |
| 3  | 6.049105 | 51.86624  | 0            |
```

How do I handle the scenario with multiple rows of the LocationPolygon table?

I'd like to know

1. if any of the points are in any of the locationPolygons?
2. what specific location polygon they are in? or if they are in more than one polygon.

Question 2 is more of an extra. Can someone help?

**Update #1**
In response to @Ben-Thul answer.

Unfortunately I don't have access/permission to make changes to the original tables, I can request access but not certain it'll be given. So not certain I'll be able to add the columns or create the index. Although I can create temp tables in a stored proc, I might be able to use test your solution that way

I stumbled on an answer like the below, but slightly worried about performance implications of using a cross join.

```
WITH cte AS (     
      select *, (GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(LineString, 4326)).STContains(geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)) as IsInALocation  from 
(     
    select Longitude, Latitude from Points nolock  
) a cross join (
    select LineString FROM LocationPolygons nolock 
) b
)

select * from cte where IsInALocation = 1
```

Obviously, it's better to look at a query plan but is the solution I stumbled upon essentially the same as yours? Are there any potential issues that I missed. Apologies for this but my sql isn't very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 shouldn't be too bad. First, some set up:

```
alter table dbo.Points add Point as (GEOGRAPHY::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326));
create spatial index IX_Point on dbo.Points (Point) with (online = on);

alter table dbo.LocationPolygon add Polygon as (GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(LineString, 4326));
create spatial index IX_Polygon on dbo.LocationPolygon (Polygon) with (online = on);
```

This will create a computed column on each of your tables that is of type `geography` that has a spatial index on it.

From there, you should be able to do something like this:

```
select pt.ID, 
   pt.Longitude,
   pt.Latitude,
   coalesce(pg.IsInLocation, 0) as IsInLocation
from Points as pt
outer apply (
   select top(1) 1 as IsInLocation 
   from dbo.LocationPolygon as pg
   where pg.Polygon.STContains(p.Point) = 1
) as pg;
```

Here, you're selecting every row from the Points table and using `outer apply` to see if any polygons contain that point. If one does (it doesn't matter which one), that query will return a 1 in the result set and bubble that back up to the driving select.

To extend this to Question 2, you can remove the `top()` from the `outer apply` and have it return either the IDs from the Polygon table or whatever you want. Note though that it'll return one row per polygon that contains the point, potentially changing the cardinality of your result set!

Comment: please see Update #1. Wanted to add as a comment but seemed to big

Comment: Understood in re: not being able to make schema changes. However, of the alternatives you name, one is "table scan both tables and brute force the join" and the other is "suck all the data into temp tables (as structures you *can* control), index those appropriately, then do the join efficiently once the data is indexed".

Comment: I imagine "sucking all the data into temp tables" is the better approach, in the sense that it'll be more efficient than doing a full table scans, thanks.

However in my testing with my tables and data set, the cross join approach is significantly quicker and the execution plan doesn't show any table scans, YMMV. This could be because I had to use temp tables in a stored proc.

Small typo on the sample code. pg.Latitude should be pt.Latitude.

Probably worth noting when creating this in a store proc via temp tables, spatial indexes need a clustered primary key on the table.